# Cannot search on email id field using solr query with wildcard

Tags: search, solr, cassandra, wildcard

I have a email id field in my table on which solr search is enabled with wildcard

For a email `abc.xyz@pqr.com`

Whenever I search `abc.xyz*` I am able to search, if I search  pqr.com* I am able to search but whenever I search `abc.xyz@pqr.com*` I dont get any results.

Below is the xml configuration of the field

```
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" 
   name="user_email_id" stored="true" type="TextField"/>
```

below is the generated query

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE 
  solr_query='{"q":"user_email_id:Shubha.Sao@techdata.com*","start":0}' LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: are you using DSE? If yes, what version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your email is split into tokens, and instead of full email you most probably get 2 tokens: `Shubha.Sao` & `techdata.com`. You can check how the text is split by your current tokenizer in the Solr UI.

Instead of the `TextField` with its default `StandardAnalyzer` you need to use either `StrField`, or customize analyzer to avoid tokenization of the email - for example, you can use `KeywordTokenizer` that will leave email intact, but you'll able to apply additional filters, like, `LowerCaseFilter`. Or you can use [UAX29URLEmailTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-UAX29URLEmailTokenizer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer the issue is solved using above config.